# Deploying TestSwarm on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, testswarm

Has anyone succeeded? I was able to get somewhere (with a PHP over FastCGI, MySql database, and URL Rewriter 2.0 Beta), but most of the code depends on the RewriteBase rule, which is not yet supported by the IIS rewriter. Needless to say, deploying it in the server root is not really an option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that only adding an application root to all paths would solve the problem. Here are the steps to deploy it:

- Install PHP via FastCGI. In php.ini,

  - enable the `short_open_tag`
  - set the `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`
- Import the rewrite rules from the .htaccess into **UrlRewriter 2.0+** (currently, beta).

  - Remove the RewriteBase + the two conditions, as well as the first rule
  - Rewrite all others to be relative, rather than absolute (`/index.php` -> `index.php`)
- Patch the URLs in TestSwarm

I'll try to submit most of this as a patch (the web.config + php patch), but I'm still very new to Git, so it may take a few days until I get it :)