# Is it possible/worth it to utilize testswarm without a browserstack account?

Tags: qunit, browserstack, testswarm

The way the github seems to talk about browserstack, it says that it's necessary to utilize testswarm. However, from what I've been reading it seems to just create virtual users/browsers to run all of your unit tests. It looks like you could still use testswarm even without an account, but I haven't seen many resources online about this.

TL;DR: If I set up a computer to just use testswarm to run tests for the browsers it has open, can I do that without having a browserstack account?

Answer (score 0):

TestSwarm was created before BrowserStack existed, so that relationship was not part of the original design. The prerequesties are:

- PHP
- MySQL
- Web Server(Apache,IIS,nodeJS,etc)
- A list of paths that reference the executable file of each browser
- A list of URLs that reference test pages you want TestSwarm to run
- TestSwarm injection script on each page:

  ```
  <script>
  var inject = 'js/inject.js?' + new Date().getTime();
  var foo = document.createElement("script");
  foo.src = inject;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(foo);
  </script>
  ```

Here are some unrelated questions on how to do a self-contained installation:

- [Deploying TestSwarm on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340626/1113772)
- [How to install and setup Testswarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629176/1113772)
- [How to create project in testswarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695572/1113772)